# Define fmt::Display and fmt::Debug together

Tags: class, rust, traits

Is it possible to define `fmt::Display` and `fmt::Debug` together, i.e. such that they use the same implementation?

Assume we have the below sample code (purely for demonstration purposes):

```rust
use std::fmt;

struct MyDate {
    pub year: u16,
    pub month: u8,
    pub day: u8
}

impl PartialEq for MyDate {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.year == other.year && self.month == other.month && self.day == other.day
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for MyDate {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}-{:02}-{:02}", self.year, self.month, self.day)
    }
}

impl fmt::Debug for MyDate {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let d1 = MyDate { year: 2008, month: 9, day: 10 };
    let d2 = MyDate { year: 2008, month: 9, day: 10 };

    println!("Date = {}", d1);  // requires fmt::Display
    assert_eq!(d1, d2);         // requires fmt::Debug
}
```

It seems that in order to print my class using `println` and write unit tests using `assert_eq`, I need to define both `fmt` traits. Is there a way to have 1 "print" implementation that simultaneously defines `fmt::Display` and `fmt::Debug`? For example something along the lines of `impl fmt::Debug, fmt::Display for MyDate { ... }` or similar?

Or is it common practice to just put `#[derive(Debug)]` in front of any class? Apologies if my question is naïve, as I am new to rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases, `Display` and `Debug` have different output. When it makes sense to use the same formatting in both cases, the code you've written is fine. It would also be fine to `#[derive(Debug)]` — it's your decision to make. I think the important thing to keep in mind is that `Debug` should *not leave anything out, and be unambiguous.*

In the case you show, the `Display` format shows all of the struct's fields completely accurately, so it's perfectly fine to reuse `Display` to implement `Debug`. If you had a lot of types like this, you could use a simple macro to generate `Debug` implementations that forward to `Display`.

By the way, I would suggest using `#[derive(PartialEq)]` instead of the manual PartialEq implementation you show. It's completely equivalent, and avoids the dangerous failure mode of forgetting to compare a newly added field.

Comment: Thanks, all of this makes sense. Just to double-check, there is no way to implement function `fmt` for both traits at the same time, like `impl fmt::Debug, fmt::Display for MyDate { fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result { ... } }` or similar?

Comment: @Phil-ZXX A macro could do that, but the built-in syntax of Rust requires one complete `impl` block per trait you're implementing.

Answer (score 0):

Performance consideration: in your `Debug` implementation, you are calling the `Display` implementation of the same object:

```rust
impl fmt::Debug for MyDate {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self) // call method from Display
    }
}
```

However, when doing this, `Debug::fmt()` calls `write!` **twice** – and this is not a cheap operation.

A better implementation would be [calling directly](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name) the method from the `Display` trait:

```rust
impl fmt::Debug for MyDate {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt::Display::fmt(self, f)
    }
}
```

Now `write!` is called only once.

> Or is it common practice to just put `#[derive(Debug)]` in front of any class?

Yes, it's very common. Implementing your custom `Debug` is interesting only if you want a custom output of the fields in your struct.

Comment: Please elaborate on "not a cheap operation". Yes using `fmt::Display::fmt(self, f)` is 1 `write!` instead of 2, when looking directly at the code. However, the compiler is smart and actually replaces `write!(f, "{}", self)` with `fmt::Display::fmt(self, f)`. Regardless, I wouldn't call `write!` in itself expensive. Overall Rust's formatting framework is _cheap_. Additionally (overall) no allocations are performed while formatting. So I don't see what would make it VERY expensive?